# Changing SRC with data attribute doesn't work- js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change src of an image with JS .
I want to take the data attribute of  another element and to place it on the src of the image:

This is the JS:

```
$(".color-click").click(function() {
    var selected = $('.color-click');
    var piccolor1 = selected.attr('data-pic1');

    $('#products-products-small').attr('src', piccolor1);
});
```

This is this is the element of the data attribute:

```
<button data-pic1="images\logo.ppg" id="circle" class="color-click"> </button>
```

This is the picture  with the src that I want to change :

```
 <img src="images/logo22.png" data-name="" class="products-products-small clicked-prod num1" id="products-products-small" onclick="showImage('<?php product_image1_products() ?>');" alt="header_bg">
```

Comment: Because you are using a backslash instead of a forward slash in the `data-pic1` value, and also you should use `var selected = $(this);`, otherwise it will refer to a collection of nodes.

Comment: try using `$(this)` instead of `$('.color-click');` and try using `selected.data('pic1');` instead of `selected.attr('data-pic1');` and your directory separator is backwards (should be `data-pic1="images/logo.ppg"`) also, you probably meant `png` instead of `ppg`.

Comment: @Occam'sRazor `.attr('data-pic1')` works just fine, the problem can't be fixed by using `.data('pic1')` as they are functionally equivalent.

Comment: and if there's only one `.color-click` then using `this` won't solve the problem either. just noting general improvements, you noted the problem in your first comment so i didn't bother writing an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using a backslash `\` instead of a forward slash `/` in the `data-pic1` value (check the file path if it actually points to an actual image), and also you should use `var selected = $(this);`, otherwise it will refer to a collection of nodes. `$(this)` in the event handler ensures that you are referring to the actual element that triggered the event, instead of returning a collection of elements.

Here is a proof-of-concept that works:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".color-click").click(function() {
    var selected = $(this);
    var piccolor1 = selected.attr('data-pic1');

    $('#products-products-small').attr('src', piccolor1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-pic1="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/B13131/FFF" id="circle" class="color-click"> Click me to change image</button>

<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/" data-name="" class="products-products-small clicked-prod num1" id="products-products-small" alt="header_bg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
$(function(){

    // image element
    var target = $(".products-products-small.num1");

    // when button is clicked
    $(".color-click").on("click", function(){

        // get image
        var src = $(this).data("img-src");

        // set image
        $(target).attr("src", src); 
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/ta90wt33/2/